# How to get rid of special tags by using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cf/cf_list/?'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I try to use BeautifulSoup to get data. However 'html.parser' does not filter bunch of `</span>` tags at the end. How to get rid of these tags.

```
{"page":1,"rows":[{"id":"160142","cell":{"fund_id":"160142", ...  ,"daily_spread":"-0.07%"}}],"total":42}</span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to parse the html. It's a json structure, so read that in with `.json()`

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cf/cf_list/?'
res = requests.get(url).json()
print (res)
```